# HTML buttons possibly conflicting with JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, html

So I made this web page that demonstrates the output of basic AES encryption and 3DES encryption. The user enters some plain text and clicks a button to produce the encrypted output of the text they entered. I want the user to be able to toggle between the different encryptions without having to retype the text.

When I click the AES button first the 3DES button won't work. But if I click the 3DES button first it will work, and I can then click the AES button after and it will work, but then the 3DES won't work again after clicking the AES button. Is it possible the JavaScripts could be conflicting somehow?

Here are the functions:

```
<script>
            function aesEncrypt()
            {
                var text = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(document.getElementById('txtPlain').value);
                var Key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("PSVJQRk9QTEpNVU1DWUZCRVFGV1VVT0=");
                var IV = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("2314345645678765");
                var encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, Key, {keySize: 128 / 8,iv: IV, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding:CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
                var encrypted = document.getElementById('txtOutput');
                encrypted.value = encryptedText;
            }

            function desEncrypt()
            {                   
                var text2 = document.getElementById('txtPlain').value;
                var key = "00f74597de203655b1ebf5f410f10eb8";
                key = CryptoJS.MD5(key);

                key.words[4] = key.words[0];
                key.words[5] = key.words[1];

                var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(64/8);
                var encrypted2 = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(text2, key, {iv: iv});                  

                document.getElementById("txtOutput").innerHTML = encrypted2;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: In one function you are using `.innerHTML` in the other you are using `.value`, it is one or the other. `<input>` elements don't have/use an `innerHTML` and likewise elements like `<div>` do not have/use a `value` property. Make sure you are using the correct property

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you, if you also paste your html code.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you, can't believed I missed that. It works now. If you post that as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.